# How can I add assets in only development mode using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to contain .env in development mode for testing but I don't want to contain .env in production mode.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please go through this link ```https://developer.school/tutorials/how-to-use-environment-variables-with-flutter-dotenv``` (courtesy developer.school and StackOverflow).

Comment: I think it is currently not possible to add assets based on the environment but there is an open issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5813